# Python code returns "====== RESTART: <path> ======" when previously working properly, batch renaming folders and files with find and replace

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, restart, batch-rename

Last week I wrote a simple code that would find "XXXX" in a folder's subfolders and files and replace it with a four digit project number (my office has template folders for new projects with many subfolders/files that all are prenamed with XXXX to be replaced with the project number, and I was tired of seeing many of these remaining unchanged throughout a project...)

Anyway, I used it on several project folders last week after writing it and tried running it again today for a new project folder, and the Shell returns

====== RESTART:  ======

[Python Shell return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOEss.png)

I hadn't modified the code nor its file location so am quite confused and related threads did not lead me to resolving this.

Here is the code:

```
import os

basedir = 'K:\Projects\1702 HANH Stanley Justice'
find = "XXXX"
replace = "1702"

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(basedir, topdown=False):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs]
    for filename in filenames:
            filename_split = os.path.splitext(filename)
            filename_zero = filename_split[0]
            extension = filename_split[1]
            if find in filename_zero:
                path1 = os.path.join(root, filename)
                path2 = os.path.join(root, filename_zero.replace(find, replace) + extension)
                os.rename(path1, path2)
                print ("file: " + path1 + " renamed to: " + path2)

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(basedir, topdown=False):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs]
    for thedir in dirs:
        if find in thedir:
            path1 = os.path.join(root, thedir)
            path2 = os.path.join(root, thedir.replace(find, replace))
            os.rename(path1, path2)
            print ("dir: " + path1 + " renamed to: " + path2)
```

Thank you in advance to whoever can advise me on how to fix this!

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions for this new project folder? You could try it on a folder that has definitely worked before to check?

Comment: I'm not strong in python shell, but the few times I've used it, I got a message like that when I started a .py after the shell is already running.  It's likely not something to worry about, but it does seem to imply that you're starting your process differently than you had been in the past (or that you never noticed that line when you ran last week).

Comment: Hi David & Scott! I realized my mistake (its a silly one) and posted it as an answer below. Thank you for your quick replies, very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had enough coffee yet today and had copied and pasted the new project folder path without replacing the back slashes with forward slashes. Worked properly when replacing those:

```
basedir = 'K:/Projects/1702 HANH Stanley Justice'
```

I'll leave this up for anyone else who experiences this caffeine deprived lapse in memory or for someone searching for a code that will find and replace a string in subfolder and file names (mine was created from combining similarly related codes I found on other threads here, was unable to find an exact one. I'm fairly new to Python so stackoverflow is very helpful!)